# Trying to use getline (string) in C++ to parse a kml file

Tags: c++

I'm using getline() to parse coordinate lines from a kml file into a vector.

The relevant part of the kml file looks like this (replaced numbers with x)...

```
<coordinates>
      -xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx,0
      -xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx,0
      -xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx,0
      -xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx,0
      -xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx,0
      -xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx,0
      -xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx,0
      -xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx,0
      -xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx,0
      -xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx,0
      -xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx,0
      -xxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxx,0
</coordinates>
```

When using getline() to print the kml file line by line it does it just fine so I figured something like this would work to parse coordinates into a vector...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

vector <string> coordinates;

int main() {
   fstream inputFile("Fish.kml", fstream::in);
   string str;

   bool running = true;
   int counter = 0;

   while (running) {
      getline(inputFile, str, '\0');

      if (str == "        <coordinates>") {
         counter++;
      }
      if (counter > 0 && str != "        </coordinates>") {
         coordinates.push_back(str);

      } 
      if (counter > 0 && str == "        </coordinates>") {
         counter = -1;
         running = false;
      }
   }

   inputFile.close();

   for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {
      cout << coordinates[i] << "\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

My thinking was to use if statements to check whether the getline() function is about to read the coordinates by checking if the line, "coordinates", has been read or not. If it has it will increase the counter to above zero that way in the next loop the rest of the program knows to start logging coordinates. Same thinking applies to stopping the code by checking to see if the line "/coordinates" has been read. It's all I could think of with my current knowledge, but obviously I must be missing something important because...

When I compile and run I don't get any errors but the program doesn't do anything. This is what it looks like, It does nothing, my computer fans kick on and I have to cancel the process...

```
irectory>test.exe
^C
```

Any ideas what is going on here?
Thank you!

Update:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

vector <string> coordinates;

int main() {
   fstream inputFile("Fish.kml", fstream::in);
   string str;

   bool running = true;
   int counter = 0;

   while (getline(inputFile, str, '\0')) {

      if (str == "        <coordinates>") {
         counter++;
      }
      if (counter > 0 && str != "        </coordinates>") {
         coordinates.push_back(str);

      } 
      if (counter > 0 && str == "        </coordinates>") {
         counter = -1;
         inputFile.close();
      }
   }


   for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {
      cout << coordinates[i] << "\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I updated the code above as suggested and it does not get stuck while executing anymore. But it does not print the vector back. I'm not sure if it is failing to record the lines of coordinates or if I didn't print it properly.

Comment: Careful with those comparisons with fixed amounts of whitespace. I don't know KML, but in general XML whitespace is not tightly regulated. One space, ten spaces, throw in a few extra lines and tabs or what have you, it's all the same. You might [be better off `find`ing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) "<coordinates>" than using string compare.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I think your right. After cleaning up the rest of the code, the if statements don't seem to be recognizing "<coordinates>". I've never used the method you've suggested before so I'll do some research, try it out and update.

Comment: Another alternative is to use an XML library to do the heavy lifting of finding the <coordinates> tag and then put the tag's contents into a [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and parse the lines in the tag with `getline`.

Comment: Seems like the way to go. I tried finding the sub-string with find("string") but I wasn't able to create a boolean parameter to use in my original code. I'm going to try out your second suggestion. Unfortunately I have little experience with XML or the libraries required to parse with but I did some quick searches and the Tinyxml2 library seems like a good place to start.

Comment: `find` returns an impossible index, `npos` when it can't find the search string, so you'd want `str.find("<coordinates>") != std::string::npos`

Comment: Been a while since I've needed an xml parser either. Most of the software I maintain that used xml had the parser baked in a decade or more ago and I'd need a hell of a business case to swap it out now. These days I'm using JSON to interface with the Python folks and custom-cooked protocols when talking to the Delphi people. Every bit as speed-obsessed as the C/C++ crowd, are the Delphi programmers.

Comment: Aha, earlier I searched for a string that didn't exist to build my parameter and the value 4294967295 was printed. I didn't think anything of it at the time. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll give it another try before attempting xml.

Answer (score 0):

replace `while(running)` with `while(getline(inputFile, str)` and remove `running` variable as it is no longer needed.

And also

```
  if (str == "<coordinates>") {
     counter++;
  }
  if (counter > 0 && str != "</coordinates>") {
     coordinates.push_back(str);

  } 
  if (counter > 0 && str == "</coordinates>") {
     counter = -1;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it from getting stuck. It still doesn't seem to be recording the coordinates as strings. The program executes fine but doesn't print back the vector..

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the following code would help you a little bit. I worte it myself. It only reads the first coordinates part.

```
//
// Created by albert on 4/1/22.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

vector<float> split(string s, string del) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = s.find(del, start);
    vector<float> ret;
    while (end != string::npos) {
        string substr = s.substr(start, end - start);
        if (!substr.empty())
            ret.push_back(stof(substr));
        start = end + del.size();
        end = s.find(del, start);
    }
    string substr = s.substr(start, end - start);
    if (!substr.empty())
        ret.push_back(stof(substr));
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    fstream istream;
    istream.open("map.kml", fstream::in);

    vector<vector<float>> coordinates;
    bool flag = false;

    if (istream.is_open()) {
        cout << "file is open" << endl;
        string str;
        while (getline(istream, str, '\n')) {
            if (str == "          <coordinates>")
                flag = true;
            else if (str == "          </coordinates>") {
                flag = false;
                break;
            } else if (flag)
                coordinates.push_back(split(str, string(1, ',')));

        }
    }

    istream.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {
        cout << coordinates[i][0] << "      " << coordinates[i][1] << "      " << coordinates[i][2] << "\n";
    }
    cout << coordinates.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```